# To generate scatter xy graph in excel using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to generate graph in excel but i want that graph to be generated in the next sheet not in the same sheet.i have pasted my macro below its working properly i just want it to be in the next sheet. please provide me some solution*

```
Sub LumData1()

    If IsEmpty(Range("B2,D2")) = False Then
        Range("B:B,D:D,H:H,I:I,J:J,M:M").Select
        Range("M1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range( _
            "$B:$B,$D:$D,$H:$H,$I:$I,$J:$J,$M:$M" _
            )
        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ActiveSheet.Name

        With ActiveChart.ChartArea
            .Width = 1060
            .Height = 420
            .Left = 0
        End With

        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Select
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).AxisGroup = 2
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Value"
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer covers not only how to solve your question in your post, but how to automatically define and set-up charts in VBA in a “cleaner” and safer way.

It's better if you avoid using `ActiveSheet`, `Select`, and `ActiveChart`. Instead always use referenced objects, in this case `Worksheets` and `ChartObject`. E.g `Dim ChtObj As ChartObject` , and later set it with `Set ChtObj = ShtCht.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 500, 500)` , where `ShtCht` is the worksheet where you create your chart.

Once you defined and set your `ChartObject`, its quite easy to modify its properties by using the `With ChtObj` , and also nested properties, by adding `With .Chart.ChartArea` under the first `With` statement.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LumData1()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim ShtSrc  As Worksheet
Dim ShtCht  As Worksheet

' change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name (where you have your chart's data)
Set ShtSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- I preffer not to work with ActiveSheet

'Set ShtCht = Worksheets("Sheet2") ' <-- set the chart's destination worksheet
Set ShtCht = Worksheets.Add ' <-- create a new worksheet to place the chart
ShtCht.Name = "Chart"

If Not IsEmpty(ShtSrc.Range("B2,D2")) Then

    Set ChtObj = ShtCht.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 500, 500)

    With ChtObj
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
        .Chart.SetSourceData ShtSrc.Range("$B:$B,$D:$D,$H:$H,$I:$I,$J:$J,$M:$M")

        ' set position of the chart to Cell M1
        .Top = ShtCht.Range("M1").Top
        .Left = ShtCht.Range("M1").Left

        ' modify chart position and dimensions
        With .Chart.ChartArea
            .Width = 1060
            .Height = 420
            .Left = 0
        End With

        With .Chart
            .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 2
            .SeriesCollection(5).AxisGroup = 2

            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Value"
            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45
        End With

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So modify the code according to your sheets name ? Is that the sheet where u keep ur data? Or where u want ur chart to be placed At ?

Comment: i have a code which convert database table to csv file and sheet name will be the table name and there will be only one sheet with data in it,after that my vbscript will run to generate graph now i want that graph in seperate sheet

Comment: Ok, so actualy you want to create a new sheet and add the chart there ?

Comment: .Top = ShtCht.Range("M1").Top
        .Left = ShtCht.Range("M1").Left    why this code is required

Comment: it's not, you can remove it, you can also add extra properties, i out it in to share some other placing capabilities it has

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP's clarification he has to make a new sheet to host the chart into

to stick to your code as much as possible:

- remove `ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ActiveSheet.Name`
- place the following code right before `End if`

  ```
  Dim myChart As Chart: Set myChart = ActiveChart
  Worksheets.Add
  myChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ActiveSheet.Name
  ```

Comment: too vague a clue to help you out. don't you agree?

Comment: i have a code which convert database table to csv file and sheet name will be the table name and there will be only one sheet with data in it,after that my vbscript will run to generate graph now i want that graph in seperate sheet. i want to create new sheet and add chart to it